# do we need sessions in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am creating a sample project for learning purpose(later on I will be working on project based on webrtc and kurento), I am using Kurento media server with it, I have modified the tutorial of the kurento server and made one sample out of it.

In all of the samples for Kurento Server they are using a UserRegistry.java where they are storing objects of UserSession as shown below:

```
public class UserSession {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSession.class);

  private final String name;
  private final WebSocketSession session;

  private String sdpOffer;
  private String callingTo;
  private String callingFrom;
  private WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEndpoint;
  private WebRtcEndpoint playingWebRtcEndpoint;
  private final List<IceCandidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();

  public UserSession(WebSocketSession session, String name) {
    this.session = session;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void sendMessage(JsonObject message) throws IOException {
    log.debug("Sending message from user '{}': {}", name, message);
    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(message.toString()));
  }

  public String getSessionId() {
    return session.getId();
  }

  public void setWebRtcEndpoint(WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEndpoint) {
    this.webRtcEndpoint = webRtcEndpoint;

    if (this.webRtcEndpoint != null) {
      for (IceCandidate e : candidateList) {
        this.webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(e);
      }
      this.candidateList.clear();
    }
  }

  public void addCandidate(IceCandidate candidate) {
    if (this.webRtcEndpoint != null) {
      this.webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    } else {
      candidateList.add(candidate);
    }

    if (this.playingWebRtcEndpoint != null) {
      this.playingWebRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
  }

  public void clear() {
    this.webRtcEndpoint = null;
    this.candidateList.clear();
  }
}
```

I have two questions on this:

1. Why do we need session object?
2. What are the alternatives(if there are any) to manage session?

Let me give some more background on 2nd question. I found out that I can run the Kurento-JavaScript-Client(I need to convert it to browser version and then I can use it.) on the client side only (That way I won't require a backend server i.e. nodejs or tomcat - this is my assumption). So in this case how would I manage session or I can totally remove the UserRegistry concept and use some other way.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to store sessions to implement signalling between the clients and the application server. See for example [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2one.html). The signalling diagram describes the messages required to start/stop/etc the WebRTC video communication.

If you are planing to get rid of the application server (i.e. move to JavaScript client completely) you can take a look to a publish/subscribe API such as [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk).

Comment: thanks but I still have a question, can I use the Kurento-JS-client totally from client side i.e. creating session from client only, or will it include any security problems ? I don't want to use any proprietary software/service for this.

Comment: Sure, Kurento is open source (Apache 2.0 license).